# matrix initialization

Tags: c++, matrix

Can someone explain the significance of the marked lines below? Generally it is initializing the matrix.

Let's say size = 3. Then it should create a matrix with 6 positions i.e a 1x6 matrix. But what is need od 2nd line here every time. And why is it pushing -1 each time?

```
for (unsigned i = 0; i < size(); i++) { 
    vector<int> *t = new vector<int>;       // (1)
    for (unsigned j = 0; j <= i; j++) { 
        t->push_back(-1);                   // (2)
    }
    matrix.push_back(*t);   
}
```

Comment: Using a pointer to vector and then dynamically allocating it as good as defeating the very purpose of using an vector. What's wrong with using: `std::vector<int> t;`??

Comment: actually i picked that part of code from a program which uses a bunch of classes which was implemented by my supervisor. i'm not sure how she used it.

Comment: hey, am new here. Unfortunately one of the answers is deleted by me without knowingly. Really sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

The code constructs and initializes the upper or lower (depending on the interpretation of indices) triangle of a square matrix. Line `(1)` allocates a new row or column vector. Line `(2)` initializes the values up to and including the matrix diagonal using an arbitrary value (`-1`). Why the code uses `-1` as the initial value can only be answered by inspecting the code or reading the accompanying documentation.

In addition to the functionality line `(1)` produces a memory leak. Since the `matrix` does not take ownership of `t` there is no way to reclaim the memory when `t` goes out of scope. The corrected code would look like this:

```
for (unsigned i = 0; i < size(); i++) { 
    vector<int> t;       // (1)
    for (unsigned j = 0; j <= i; j++) { 
        t.push_back(-1); // (2)
    }
    matrix.push_back(t);
}
```

Notice that line `(1)` allocates an object that is automatically destroyed when it goes out of scope. This fixes the memory leak in your original code. Assuming that size is 3 this would produce:

```
-1 -1 -1          -1
   -1 -1    or    -1 -1
      -1          -1 -1 -1
```

depending on whether the first index to matrix references rows or columns.

Comment: thanks dude. Here, later in the program some values will be placed in the matrix variable after some calculations.